# Can I automate LibreJS testing?

Tags: open-source, javascript, web-browser, automation

I have previously used the [LibreJS extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/librejs/) to test that web pages I visit don't fall into [the JavaScript Trap](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/javascript-trap.html). In other words, test that their JavaScript code is freely licensed.

However, I'd now like to test a large number of pages. What tools can I use to directly automate LibreJS, or produce similar reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use my tool https://github.com/nexB/scancode-toolkit that is one of the best tool to detect licenses (Used by Eclipse, Linux maintainers, RedHat/openshift and many more).

To use as a LibreJS replacement, download a URL as a "complete" web page and scan the resulting folder to generate a report. [If you have any inaccurate or not definitive license detection compared to LibreJS this is a bug to report!](https://github.com/nexB/scancode-toolkit/issues/835)

scancode-toolkit does not currently have a notion of libre or non-libre, so you will have to interpret that for yourself from the licenses listed in the report. Adding that as a feature would be welcome.